# what is best config for php-fpm and nginx with this server?

Tags: nginx, centos7, php-fpm

I have a server with following specs and was wondering what's the best config I can set for nginx and php-fpm?

RAM: 96GB
CPU: 48 Cores
SSD: 200GB
OS: Drupal
Daily users: 52k to 55K
PHP: 7.3
Mysql: 8.0

I have the following nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 domain.com www.domain.com;
    root /some_directory/;
    index index.php index.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    /// some CMS confis ///
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
```

and use the defailt php-fpm settings but I sure do need to change it since I'm getting
`[pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers),` error

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
F) complete www.MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report or similar. 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Could you post current content of php-fpm.conf for analysis?  Your 48 cores should have some influence on limits of pm-min max values used.

Comment: @WilsonHauck here it is: pm.max_children = 530 pm.start_servers = 48 pm.max_spare_servers = 96 pm.max_requests = 500'

Comment: What is the value for pm?  STATIC - ONDEMAND - DYNAMIC?  Would you like performance tuning suggestions for current workload?  If yes, please post requested Additional Information.  Thanks.

Comment: @WilsonHauck the value is set to dynamic. other than those modifications, nothing else is changed

Comment: Since you have only 48 cores, please consider more than PHP-FPM needs to run on your server.  Consider trying pm.max_children =10 (concurrent running processes) pm.start_servers =12  pm_min_spare_servers = 12  pm.max_spare_servers = 12 and keep pm.Max_requests = 500  (queue limit).  This will allow MySQL to breathe for processing active requests.  Any thoughts on workload performance tuning?

Comment: @WilsonHauck when I was using the default values for php-fpm, I'd get 524 error  on my website and in error logs, I had '[pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers)' error. Ever since I changed it, no more down time, but today, I got PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections in lock_may_be_available() after few days which is weird! I restarted mysql then the site came back online. I'm not too sure about the values you suggested, because those values gave me error every day

Comment: Please post your entire A) php-fpm configuration and B) entire report from phpinfo request - for analysis. Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thank you, here are the info you requeste:
A) https://pastebin.com/1VWeYfa4
B) https://mega.nz/file/6FQhgIIA#mgD5JNhQoE-bzrpfoAS2nd7T-Umq27BWvAsisZt4btE

Comment: Could you provide the phpinfo as .txt rather than .png formatted report?

Comment: @WilsonHauck for sure. here it is 
https://mega.nz/file/zIAGWD4L#YYhQQLX012b2cgSGjPqS5VqOhjfdbBuHRl5y_hLmYeU
PS: Any ideas why I'm getting the database error? I mean Mysql takes 12GB ram in htop and every day around exact time I get the PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections in lock_may_be_available() error. It started to show up after I disabled Memcached (it was messing with my database, so I had ro turn it off) but before that, it was running without a problem. I also saw your answers to another similar problem which is why I'm looking forward for your help. thank you

Comment: Since the 1040 error occurs every day near an exact time, please gather FIVE MINUTES before the expected error, the requested DB additional information  and requested OS additional information as requested a few days ago.  It will be Monday before I have analyzed your PHP info supplied over the past couple days.  My basic perception is your 48 cores CAN NOT support pm.max_children of 530.  Besides your server has multiple apps running besides PHP-FPM, MySQL has to have use of some cores to complete your clients processing requests.  Put a throttle on it, as requested.

Comment: sam oolix, PHP-FPM suggestions will be delayed until you can provide Additional DB info requested Sep 4, 2022 at 12:54  and Additional OS info requested Sep 4, 2022 at 12:56.   Looking forward to assisting with actionable suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sorry I forgot to post them. Here are the details you asked for:
https://pastebin.com/0ZR4dU6h  innodb
https://pastebin.com/je1VSKUL  status
https://pastebin.com/52VXPyuR  full process list
https://pastebin.com/7jXGdsYp  global variables
https://pastebin.com/EAjPwvs5  select 
https://pastebin.com/B2jBuWnK  global status
https://pastebin.com/q37Sa04V Mysql Tuner

PS: I had to restart mysql because of the 1040 error, but I will repost tuner info and global status again after 24 hours

Comment: Sam, See Skype for observations on data posted, please.

Answer (score 0):

Improvements should be looked in following components in this order:

1. Drupal optimization / caching options, for example utilizing APCu for data caching
2. MySQL database optimization / settings
3. PHP optimization (Opcode cache)

There isn't much point optimizing nginx, since majority of request processing happens in PHP / MySQL.

Also, it is impossible to just give "best config", because the actual configuration depends a lot on several details. Your best bet is the scientific approach: Make changes, measure the improvement. Repeat until performance is in satisfactory level.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I actually have those 3 steps covered (APCu, DB Optimization and OPCache)
Any ideas about the reasonable numbers for php-fpm child and etc settings?

Comment: You should monitor your CPU load, and increase the numbers of PHP-FPM childs as high as possible without making CPU load too high. That doesn't affect performance as such, it only allows more visitors before the limits block them.

Comment: Right now the only thing that uses Most of my CPU is mysql, since drupal stores its cache in database (NOT WISE AT ALL !) and there's nothing much I can do about that. The cache is set to clear by cronjob, and here's what I;ve decided to use: 'pm.max_children = 530
pm.start_servers = 48
pm.max_spare_servers = 96
pm.max_requests = 500' 
is it ok for now? PS: I've set memcached memory to 4GB as well

Comment: Change Drupal to cache its data to memcached or APCu. For example, https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-optimize-drupal-8-caching-with-memcached-on-cpanel-hosting/ step 4 tells how to change Drupal to use memcached for its cache.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I will try to use that method.